# How to get the "Stats Life" trophy

Tags: achievements, wipeout-hd-fury

In Wipeout HD Fury, how to get the "Stats Life" trophy?
The trophy says: "Attain and view every stat in the game". Quite cryptic for me. I then checked on [trophy guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/wipeout-hd/guide/).
They say:

> After you load up Wipeout with the Fury pack, go to Options, then Extras, and then Statistics. Where ever you see a 0, you need to add something there. You’ll probably have to do a tournament with the new tracks (Talon’s Junction Forward/Reverse, The Amphiseum Forward/Reverse, Modesto Heights Forward/Reverse, and Tech De Ra Forward/Reverse ) and do a round of Zone Battle, Eliminator, and Detonator (you might have to do a round on each of the tracks dedicated to these modes as well, Pro Tozo, Mallavol, Corridon 12, and Syncopia).
>   If after doing all of that the trophy doesn’t unlock, go back to the Stats page and look through every page. Either you missed one or the trophy will unlock when you’re looking at the Stats page.

Now, when I'm checking the stats page, I don't have any number at 0. Should I also have each of the bar charts above 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copying the below quote from [this link](http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/trophy-guides/7321-wipeout-hd-fury-trophy-guide.html)

> Under Options on the main menu there
>   is a new area called Extras. Under
>   Extras you will find Statistics which
>   is what you need to view to get this
>   trophy. To obtain all of the stats you
>   must race on every track, yes all 24
>   tracks, and fire and absorb every
>   weapon. You will notice that is shows
>   your progress on Arcade Perfect on the
>   first page, don't worry you don't have
>   to earn Arcade Perfect to get Stats
>   Life. UPDATE: You must do a split
>   screen race on any track as well. If
>   you don't have two controllers you can
>   use either a Guitar Hero guitar or
>   your PS3 DVD remote, just set the
>   remote to controller 2.

If you follow a link, the author makes a special note about the split screen race being necessary. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'll check that (I first have to find someone for the split-screen...). All tracks means clockwise AND counter-clockwise? I suppose so...

Comment: Got it :) So, all tracks means of course in both direction as clearly stated on the stats page. For the split screen, I did it alone with two controllers, doing the race for one team and then for the other one :)